# Groovy append to json file

Tags: groovy

I have a jenkins pipeline script, where I am collecting the data as json format. I want all the data to be updated in a string and finally write to a json file. But in my script, the value is over written.

```
                    for(String item: jsonObj.devices) {
                        os = item.os
                        if(!os.contains("\\.")) {
                            osV = os + ".0"
                        } else{
                            osV = os
                        }
                        def osValues = osV.split('\\.')
                        if(values[0].toInteger() <= osValues[0].toInteger()) {
                            name = item.name
                            def data = [
                                name: "$name",
                                os: "$os",
                            ]
                            def json_str = JsonOutput.toJson(data)
                            def json_beauty = JsonOutput.prettyPrint(json_str)
                            writeJSON(file: 'message1.json', json: json_beauty)
                        }
                    }
```

I want all the data to be collected and finally write to sample.json. Please let me know where I am wrong.

Comment: you need to add the `json_str` variables together into some common variable each time through the loop and then just do the last 3 lines at the end of the `for` loop rather than each time through.

Comment: Can you show that @frankM_DN

Comment: just create the `json_str` variable before the loop so something like `def json_str = ""` then at the end of the loop do `json_str += JsonOutput.toJson(data)` and then move the last 3 lines outside of the `for` loop

Comment: Nope, only the first set of data was written in the file @frankM_DN